How can I access MSA user's license details?
I want to get the license details of (MSA and AAD) users to check their M365 subscription details.
I am able to get these details using https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/licenseDetails,for enterprise(AAD) users, but same API doesn't work for non-enterprise(MSA) users

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
